# A part of my code is not working in a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I don't know why but it is guessing passwords but it is not ending the program when it gets the guess right. Any help is much appreciated!

```
#imports
import time, random

#Welcome
print("Welcome to Password Guess!")
pass1 = input("Please insert your phone password:")

#Start system

guessclock = 0

start1 = 1

i = 1
while i < 2:
    while i < 2:
        guess1 = random.randint(1, 2)
        guessclock += 1
        print(guess1)
    if pass1 == guess1:
        i = 3
        print("Password guessed")
        print("It took", guessclock)
        print("Attempts")
```

Comment: add a ```break``` statement

Comment: What's the pointed of the nested `while` with the same condition? Also, you never change `i`, so you will have an infinite loop

Comment: Added break statement still does not work.

Comment: You need to update your variable such that when the condition is met, it breaks out of the loop. For instance, `i = i + 1`.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Where should your program figure out how to exit?  What variables didn't change, or what condition didn't work the way you expected?

Comment: Also, note that your program is not self-sufficient: it hangs waiting for input.  Don't make us guess how to make your error appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replacing

```
pass1 = input("Please insert your phone password:")
```

with

```
pass1 = int(input("Please insert your phone password:")) # turns pass1 into an integer
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much

Comment: Is there any way I could make it not re guess combos?

Comment: Make a list containing all the possible combos for example: `combos = [1, 2]` then use the `random.choice` to pick one out of the two combos, then remove the picked combos and have random choose another combo. `combos.remove(random.choice(combos))`. Now you would have one less item to guess from, removing re-guessed combos

Comment: Is there a way I can do it without listing 1 million combinations in a list.

Comment: I don't think so, however, you can use `combos = list(range(start, stop, step=1))` where range ends just before `stop`, this generates a list of combos. Or use can use list comprehension `[i for i in range(start, stop, step)]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better version (without double-while loops and with int conversion):

```
#imports
import time, random

#Welcome
print("Welcome to Password Guess!")
pass1 = int(input("Please insert your phone password:"))

#Start system

guessclock = 0

start1 = 1

i = True
while i:
    guess1 = random.randint(1, 2)
    guessclock += 1
    print(guess1)
    if pass1 == guess1:
        i = False
print("Password guessed")
print("It took", guessclock)
print("Attempts")
```